# ethers.queryFilter returns TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')

Tags: ethers.js, ganache, ganache-cli, typescript

I have a typescript project using ethersjs to connect and interact with a smart contract, on a fork made with ganache. This specific code is throwing an error:

```
  const eventFilter: ethers.EventFilter = await governor.filters.ProposalCreated as ethers.EventFilter;

  const proposalsEvents = await governor.queryFilter(eventFilter);//FAILS
```

Returning:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
    at /projectdir/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/forking/forked_blockchain.js:850:37
    at /projectdir/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/forking/forked_blockchain.js:136:11
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

Does anybody knows why would that be?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the fork. Since I didn't specify a block number for the `queryFilter` it tried to gather info from the genesis block but it has only the last 128 block available to query from.